# Some files can't be saved/updated when selected in Finder

Tags: finder, error, adobe

Some times when I select files in Finder (also use TotalFinder in case it affects somehow) they are locked from changes.

Saving a file (for example, from Fireworks) shows the typical "file already in use" error message.

Any ideas on how to prevent that?

Comment: What version of OSX are you using?

Comment: OSX 10.9.2 but it happened at least since 10.9

Comment: is it just with adobe apps?

Comment: It doesn't happen with all apps. MS Word or others work just fine. However, I see this behavior also when copying files to a NAS. It won't let me copy because file is in use (selected by Finder). I used 'lsof' command to make sure is Finder's fault.